# Why does my code show undefined for the language when I refresh, but then shows the correct language?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, translation, i18next, react-i18next

```
import i18next from 'i18next';
import { useEffect } from 'react';
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';
import { initReactI18next } from 'react-i18next';
import { applyClientHMR } from 'i18next-hmr/client';
import LanguageDetector from 'i18next-browser-languagedetector';
import Backend from 'i18next-http-backend';
import i18n from 'i18next';

import intervalPlural from 'i18next-intervalplural-postprocessor';
import { uniq } from 'lodash';

import header from '../public/static/locales/en/header.json';

const defaultNamespaces = [
  'header',
];

interface Translation {
  [key: string]: string;
}

interface Translations {
  [namespace: string]: Translation;
}

export interface I18nResources {
  translations: Translations;
  namespaces: string[];
}

type LocaleSetupProps = {
  i18nResources?: I18nResources;
  fallback?: string;
};

export default function useNextLocale({
  i18nResources = { translations: {}, namespaces: [] },
}: LocaleSetupProps) {
  const router = useRouter();

  console.log(router.locale);
  console.log(i18n.language);
  const { translations, namespaces } = i18nResources;
  const locale = router.locale;
  const namespacesWithDefaults = uniq([...namespaces, ...defaultNamespaces]);

  if (!i18n.isInitialized) {
    i18n
      .use(intervalPlural)
      .use(initReactI18next)
      .use(Backend)
      .use(LanguageDetector)
      .init({
        lng: locale,
        preload: locale ? [locale] : [],
        ns: namespacesWithDefaults,
        supportedLngs: router.locales,
        fallbackLng: 'en',
        react: { useSuspense: false },
        debug: process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production',
        load: 'all',
        backend: {
          loadPath: '/static/locales/{{lng}}/{{ns}}.json',
        },
        saveMissing: process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production',
      });

    if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production') {
      applyClientHMR(i18n);
    }
  }

  i18n.setDefaultNamespace(namespaces[0]);

  if (locale) {
    if (!i18next.language) {
      i18next.changeLanguage(locale);
    }

    namespacesWithDefaults.forEach((ns) => {
      if (!i18next.hasResourceBundle(locale, ns)) {
        i18next.addResourceBundle(locale, ns, translations[ns]);
      }
    });
  }

  return { locale };
}

export async function getTranslations(
  locale: string | undefined,
  namespaces: string[],
) {
  const translations: Translations = {};
  const namespacesWithDefaults = uniq([...namespaces, ...defaultNamespaces]);

  for (const ns of namespacesWithDefaults) {
    const { default: data = {} }: { default: Translation } = await import(
      `../public/static/locales/${locale}/${ns}.json`
    );

    translations[ns] = data;
  }

  return { translations, namespaces: namespacesWithDefaults };
}
```

I'm encountering a perplexing issue with my code, and I could really use some assistance. The problem arises when I refresh my website, as it initially displays "undefined" before eventually switching to the correct content. This behavior has left me scratching my head, as I've tried numerous troubleshooting steps to no avail.

I've spent quite some time attempting to resolve this issue, but unfortunately, none of my attempted solutions have proven successful thus far. I've scoured through my code, looking for any potential errors or inconsistencies, but everything appears to be in order. It's frustrating to see the "undefined" message appear momentarily before the content is finally displayed correctly.

Answer (score 0):

As I reviewed your code,

1- what you imported is `i18n`

`import i18n from 'i18next';`

2- what you are trying to log to console is `i18n.language`

`console.log(i18n.language);`

3- But then later in code you're checking `i18next.language`

`if (!i18next.language) {`

The problem probably lies there.

Comment: even when i  change everything to i18n or i18next it does not resolve my issue :(